# Graph Laplacian for weight matrix with negative edges

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite, eigenfunctions, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

How can I normalize my weight matrix to get a positive semi-definite Laplacian, if I am using a weight matrix with negative edges?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All eigenvalues are non-negative if the graph weights are all non-negative, so if I have a weight matrix with negative values, how can I normalize it to order to get a positive semi-definite Laplacian

Comment: You need positive edge weights. You can do this in many ways (take absolute values, add a positive constant to all edge weights, set the negative ones to zero, etc.). The way you make the edge weights positive should depend on your application; why are some weights negative and what does it mean when they are?

Comment: The application is gene network construction, and the negative values are partial correlations, I tried adding changing to positive values, however, my professor believes doing this removes valuable information from my data, which is negative linear relationships